# How to close only currently opened modal in angular using NgbModal?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I want to close only currently opened modal in angular using NgbModal. but 'dismissAll()' method of NgbModal closes all the currently opened modals.

I Created Two Entry Components in the Projects

- ConsumerList   //Main Component

  -AddConsumer  //Entry Component  //ChildModal

  -ShowAllConsumers //Entry Component  //ParentModal

My Code :

```
    **//ShowAllConsumers.html  (Parent Modal)**

    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Consumers</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button style="float: right" type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="CloseModal()">
          Back
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="gMap" style="min-height: 550px;width: 100%;height:100%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ng-template id='CLocation' #Consumer let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
      <kt-AddConsumer [InputModel]="this.SelectedConsumer"></kt-AddConsumer>
    </ng-template>

    **//AddConsumer.html (Child Modal)**

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Edit Consumer </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button style="float: right" id = "btnBack" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="CloseModal()">
            Back
        </button>
        <button style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"
            *ngIf="this.Operation === 'ADD'" type="submit"
            mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="SaveConsumer()">
            Save
        </button>
        <button style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"
            *ngIf="this.Operation === 'EDIT'" type="submit"
            mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="SaveConsumer()">
            Edit
        </button>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="map" style="min-height: 550px;width: 100%;height:100%">
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

output of above code is :

[image: output]

```
**//ShowAllConsumers.ts**


import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'kt-ShowAllConsumers',
  templateUrl: './ShowAllConsumers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ShowAllConsumers.component.scss']
})
export class ShowAllConsumersComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() InputModel: ConsumerModel[];
  AreaCoordinates: AreaGeoCoordinates[];
  @ViewChild('Consumer') ConsumerRef: ElementRef;
  gMap: any;
  marker: any;
  Operation: string;
  SelectedConsumer: ConsumerModel;

  constructor(
    public _ngZone: NgZone,
    public chRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private ngbModalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window["angularComponentRef"] = { component: this, zone: this._ngZone };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", this.InitializeMap());
  }

  InitializeMap() {
    this.gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMap'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lat: 18.519834, lng: 73.857944 },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    this.ShowCoordinates();
  }

  OpenLocationModal(AreaName, AreaRefNo, ConsumerAddress, ConsumerName, ConsumerNo, DistributorID, Latitude, Longitude, MobileNo, Pin, Source, UniqueConsumerId) {
    var m = new ConsumerModel();
    m.AreaName = AreaName;
    m.AreaRefNo = AreaRefNo;
    m.ConsumerAddress = ConsumerAddress;
    m.ConsumerName = ConsumerName;
    m.ConsumerNo = ConsumerNo;
    m.DistributorID = DistributorID;
    m.Latitude = Latitude;
    m.Longitude = Longitude;
    m.MobileNo = MobileNo;
    m.Pin = Pin;
    m.Source = Source;
    m.UniqueConsumerId = UniqueConsumerId;
    debugger;
    this.SelectedConsumer = m;
    //Opening the child modal
    var modalRef1 = this.ngbModalService.open(this.ConsumerRef, {
      windowClass: 'modalclass2',
      centered: true,
      size: "lg",
      backdrop: "static"
    });
    modalRef1.result.then(
      () => {
        alert("Close button clicked")
      }
      });
  }



  CloseModal() {
    this.ngbModalService.dismissAll();
  }

}

**//AddConsumer.ts**

import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'kt-AddConsumer',
  templateUrl: './AddConsumer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./AddConsumer.component.scss'],
  providers: [AreawiseConsumerListComponent,NgbActiveModal]
})
export class AddConsumerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() InputModel: ConsumerModel;
  constructor(
    private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  CloseModal() {
    this.activeModal.dismiss();
  }

}
```

When I click on Back button of child Modal, All two modal getting closed but I want to close only child modal.

Is there any way to achieve the same ?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

Comment: I tried for the NgbActiveModal but it is not working

Comment: @Tejas i will recommend you to create a reusable modal component , check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360691/how-to-make-a-modal-reusable-in-angular-2/56559002#56559002

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddConsumer.ts` you need to inject a reference to `NgbActiveModal` and the selected consumer in the constructor.

You can also remove the hack code with the template and properties/input/binding for `SelectedConsumer`.

```
...
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class AddConsumer {
  constructor(
    @Inject('selectedConsumer') private selectedConsumer: ConsumerModel,
    private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    ...
  ) {
  }

  CloseModal() {
    this.activeModal.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Here is where you open the dialog, injecting the `selectedConsumer`:

```
OpenLocationModal(AreaName, AreaRefNo, ConsumerAddress, ConsumerName, ConsumerNo, DistributorID, Latitude, Longitude, MobileNo, Pin, Source, UniqueConsumerId) {
    var m = new ConsumerModel();
    m.AreaName = AreaName;
    m.AreaRefNo = AreaRefNo;
    m.ConsumerAddress = ConsumerAddress;
    m.ConsumerName = ConsumerName;
    m.ConsumerNo = ConsumerNo;
    m.DistributorID = DistributorID;
    m.Latitude = Latitude;
    m.Longitude = Longitude;
    m.MobileNo = MobileNo;
    m.Pin = Pin;
    m.Source = Source;
    m.UniqueConsumerId = UniqueConsumerId;
    //Opening the child modal
    var modalRef1 = this.ngbModalService.open(AddConsumerComponent, {
        windowClass: 'modalclass2',
        centered: true,
        size: "lg",
        backdrop: "static",
        injector: Injector.create({
            providers: [{
                provide: 'selectedConsumer', //maybe use an InjectionToken instead of a string
                useValue: m,
            }],
            parent: this.injector,
        }),
    });
    modalRef1.result.then(
        () => {
            alert("Close button clicked")
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did the same code and got the error : NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbActiveModal! ....... then I also provide NgbActiveModal in component providers but still it is not working

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211922/ng-bootstrap-modal-component-no-provider-error

Comment: @Tejas you don't need to add NgbActiveModal in the providers list. Also post the code where you open this modal. If you use the NgbModal service to show it, it provides the active modal ref.

Comment: I have updated the code ......Yes.. I used NgbModal Service for opening of modal but it not provides Active modal ref

Comment: @Tejas the problem is in the way you open the modal... You should inject the `SelectedConsumer` in `AddConsumer`, don't do that hack. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Sorry Sir...I tried your code...but still getting error : NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbActiveModal.....actually I injected the selectedCosumer in following way : <kt-AddConsumer [InputModel]="this.SelectedConsumer"></kt-AddConsumer>

Comment: @Tejas are you sure you also updated `ShowAllConsumersComponent`?

Comment: Yes Sir...I am sure ... I added the injector provided by you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196929/discussion-between-tejas-and-andrei-ttar).